# pandas - How to aggregate two columns and keeping all other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below synopsis of a df:

```
  movie id       movie title release date                                           IMDb URL                      genre  user id  rating  
0         2  GoldenEye (1995)     1-Jan-95  http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?GoldenEye%20(...  Action|Adventure|Thriller        5       3  
1         2  GoldenEye (1995)     1-Jan-95  http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?GoldenEye%20(...  Action|Adventure|Thriller      268       2  
2         2  GoldenEye (1995)     1-Jan-95  http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?GoldenEye%20(...  Action|Adventure|Thriller      276       4  
3         2  GoldenEye (1995)     1-Jan-95  http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?GoldenEye%20(...  Action|Adventure|Thriller      217       3  
4         2  GoldenEye (1995)     1-Jan-95  http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?GoldenEye%20(...  Action|Adventure|Thriller       87       4
```

What i'm looking for is count 'user id' and average 'rating' and keep all other columns intact. So the result will be something like this:

```
  movie id       movie title release date                                           IMDb URL                      genre  user id     rating  
0         2  GoldenEye (1995)     1-Jan-95  http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?GoldenEye%20(...  Action|Adventure|Thriller      50       3.75  
1         3  Four Rooms (1995)    1-Jan-95  http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?GoldenEye%20(...  Action|Adventure|Thriller      35       2.34
```

any idea how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Something like df1 = df[['movie id',rating']].groupby('movie id').agg(np.mean)  then merge it back in pd.merge(df,df1,on='movie id',how='left')

Comment: What do you mean by "count user id"?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke  Looks like the df is all user ratings so mobaset wants the number of ratings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all the values are in the columns you are aggregating over are the same for each group then you can avoid the join by putting them into the group.

Then pass a dictionary of functions to `agg`. If you set `as_index` to `False` to keep the grouped by columns as columns:

```
df.groupby(['movie id','movie title','release date','IMDb URL','genre'], as_index=False).agg({'user id':len,'rating':'mean'})
```

Note `len` is used to count

Answer (score 0):

When you have too many columns, you probably do not want to type all of the column names. So here is what I came up with:

```
column_map = {col: "first" for col in df.columns}
column_map["col_name1"] = "sum"
column_map["col_name2"] = lambda x: set(x) # it can also be a function or lambda
```

now you can simply do

```
df.groupby(["col_to_group"], as_index=False).aggreagate(column_map)
```